# how to differenciate group messages in getting sms/mms from device?

Tags: android, cursor, message

In my application i want to get sms/mms from device and display the messages in listview.By using the following code to get the all sms from device.

```
public void readSmsFromDevice() {

    preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(BackgroundService.this);
    final_msg_time = preferences.getLong("msgtime", 0);


    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    String[] projection = { "address", "body", "date", "type" };
    String where = "date" + ">" + final_msg_time;

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, where,null, "date");
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        if(ProfileFragment.stop)
        {
            break;
        }else{
        try {
            //

         Message mess1=new Message();
         try{
            String _id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            mess1.setId(_id);
         }catch(Exception e)
         {              
             mess1.setId("null");            
         }
         try{
            String number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            number = number.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");

            if (number.trim().length() > 10) {
                mess1.setNumber(number.substring(number.length() - 10,
                        number.length()));
                mess1.setAddress(number.substring(number.length() - 10,
                        number.length()));

            } else {

                mess1.setNumber(number);
                mess1.setAddress(number);

            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            mess1.setBody(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body")));
            String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));           
            Long millisecond = Long.parseLong(cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex("date")));
            String dateString = DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a",
                    new Date(millisecond)).toString();
            mess1.setDate_millis(millisecond);
            mess1.setDate(dateString);
            mess1.setType(type);
            mess1.setmessagetype("sms");
            messages.add(mess1);
        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }
    }

    cur.close();

}
```

By using this method i am getting all sms from device.But my question is how to differenciate group message.In group message one message sent different contact numbers(senders).So in normal message application group message displayed in separate column and single message displayed in separate column.So my application also i have to display the messages like message application.So in this cursor how to identify group message?Is there any column is available to identify group message?So please suggest me how to do taht.Thanks In Advance.....

Answer (score 0):

the thread THREAD_ID column will give you all the messages in the same conversation. You can then use the address column to differentiate the senders of the messages in the group message.
You should also use the Telephony class that was introduced in API 19 instead of the content resolver. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html